# Converting a JSON to CSV

Tags: python

```
import json
import csv
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
import watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding.features.v1 as \
    features


natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
    version='2017-02-27',
    username='b6dd1781-02e4-4dca-a706-05597d574221',
    password='c3ked6Ttmmc1')

response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
    text='Bruce Banner is the Hulk and Bruce Wayne is BATMAN! '
         'Superman fears not Banner, but Wayne.',
    features=[features.Entities()])

response1 = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
    text='Bruce Banner is the Hulk and Bruce Wayne is BATMAN! '
         'Superman fears not Banner, but Wayne.',
    features=[features.Keywords()])

#print response.items()[0][1][1]
make= json.dumps(response, indent=2)
make1= json.dumps(response1, indent=2)
print make
print make1

x = json.loads(make)

f = csv.writer(open("Entities.csv", "wb+"))


f.writerow(["relevance", "text", "type", "count"])

for x1 in x:
    f.writerow([x1['relevance'],
                x1['text'],
                x1['type'],
                x1['count']])
```

The make variable above contains a JSON that has to be converted to a CSV and while doing so I am getting a type Error that is TypeError: string indices must be integers. The actual problem is I am not able to pass through the entities and get in to the key value pairs can someone tell me what could be done here?

Structure of JSON

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "relevance": 0.931351,
      "text": "Bruce Banner",
      "type": "Person",
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "relevance": 0.288696,
      "text": "Wayne",
      "type": "Person",
      "count": 1
    }
  ],
  "language": "en"
}
```

Comment: Please include a short program that produces the error you've described. Please include your actual and expected output of the program.

Comment: you could put the data in excel and record the macro that parses that data into .csv Then you could convert that script into python, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dump the json structre and data into a file - you can use this script to handle the key:values into a CSV file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri May 26 01:24:44 2017

@author: ITZIK CHAIMOV
"""
import csv


labels = []     #prepare empty list of labels and values
values = []

fin = open('dataFile.json', 'r')    #assuming you have dumped the data into a json file (as you showed at the example)
#numberOfLines = fin.readlines()
#for line in range(numberOfLines):
buffer = fin.readline()
buffer = fin.readline()
while (buffer!=''):
    while not(buffer.__contains__('"en"')):
        if  buffer.__contains__('{'):
            buffer = fin.readline()
            while not(buffer.__contains__('}')):
                labels.append(buffer.split(':')[0].strip())
                values.append(buffer.split(':')[1].strip())
                buffer = fin.readline()
        buffer=fin.readline()
    break
fin.close()
n=size(labels)
firstLabel = labels[0]
i=0
for lbl in labels:
    if ((firstLabel == lbl) & (i!=0)):
        break
    i+=1

tbl = []
tbl.append(labels[0:i])
for j in range(int(n/i)):
    tbl.append(values[j*i:(j+1)*i])


fout = open('testfile.csv', 'w')
csv_write = csv.writer(fout)
csv_write.writerows(tabl)
fout.close()
```

[image: CSV file shown at Excel - the '/" signs can be removed]

Answer (score -1):

`x1` returns the keys of the structure `x`. To access the value associated to each key, you need to do `x[x1]`, otherwise, you are looking for an index called `'relevance'` in `x1` which is a key of type string.

`x` contains the entire JSON structure. You are only interested in the list (consisting of a single dictionary) indexed by the key "entities". So you first access only that, and then go through each key-value pair.

```
x1 = x['entities'][0]
f.writerow([x1['relevance'],
                x1['text'],
                x1['type'],
                x1['count']])
```

The second key is `language', which returns a single string 'en', and not a dictionary.

Comment: Can u show me how to do it by editing the code? I understand your logic but can understand how to code  it